# How do I split a homotopy idempotent?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I want to check that the homotopy category of cochain complexes of an idempotent splitting, preadditive category is idempotent splitting.

Let $a\xleftarrow{e}{}a$ be an idempotent chain map up to chain homotopy, $e^2\sim e$; that is, there exists maps $a_{i-1}\xleftarrow{h_i}a_i$ with $e_i^2-e_i=h_{i+1}d_i+d_{i-1}h_i$. Assuming that idempotents split in the underlying category, how can I construct a chain complex $im\left(e\right)$ with chain maps $im\left(e\right){\xleftarrow{p}\atop \xrightarrow[i]{}}a$ such that $ip\sim e$ and $pi\sim1_{im\left(e\right)}$?

Comment: Also, you probably mean "cochain", not "chain".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me re-denote your chain complex $a$ by $C$. You can define a chain complex $D$ as the *mapping telescope* of the infinite sequence
$$
\cdots\overset e\to \quad C \quad \overset e\to \quad C \quad \overset e\to \cdots
$$
This can be constructed as follows:  Form the homotopy coequalizer of the pair of maps
$$
1,S_a: \bigoplus_{\Bbb N} \quad C \quad \to  \quad \bigoplus_{\Bbb N} \quad C 
$$
where $1$ is the identity and $S_a$ is given by applying $a$ and then shifting by one unit to the right in the index. (The homotopy coequalizer is gotten from this diagram by replacing the target 
$\oplus_{\Bbb N}  C$ with its cylinder $\oplus_{\Bbb N}  C \otimes I$ and forming the coequalizer of the two inclusions given by $1$ and $S_a$ on each end.)

The effect of this construction is to homotopically invert the map $e$, giving you a model for 
$C[e^{-1}]$.  There is an evident inclusion
$i: C \to D$. There is a map $D \to C$ which is defined on the $k$-th summand using the 
map $e^{\circ k}$. This will do what you want it to.

Comment: $\otimes$? $I$? What do we know about our category?

Comment: Good point. Does Eitan's category have mapping cylinders and can one form colimits? I don't actually know what a "chain homotopy category" is. Maybe he means the homotopy category of a category of chain complexes. What are these complexes defined over?

Comment: Yes, I mean that: the homotopy category of a category of chain complexes. In general I just want the underlying category to be Ab-enriched and idempotent-splitting. The categories I'm looking at are not monoidal though.

Comment: @Eitan: Good. Then my argument does apply. 

Comment: But don't you assume that there are countable coproducts (or co-powers) in your argument? In that case it's a general fact about such pre-additive categories proved with essentially the same 'mapping telescope argument', see Freyd, Splitting homotopy idempotents, in: Proceedings of the Conference on Categorical Algebra, La Jolla, CA, 1965, Springer, New York, 1966, pp. 173–176.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks for the reference and the observation.

Comment: What is $\otimes$ if the category is not moonoidal?

Comment: Also, it really doesn't work without countable sums? Can we prove it?

Comment: @darij: $C \otimes I$ is the mapping cylinder over the identity $C \to C$, see Weibel Ch. 1.6 for an explicit description of the complex. The notation $- \otimes I$ is a standard abuse from homotopical algebra.

Comment: Ah! (I know. Homological and -topical algebra seems to consist of definitions, theorems and abuses of notation.)